# Filter nested array based on its nested values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filtering

If I had the following data, how would I go about filtering the `students` array in each `node` using ES6 syntax, so it only returns students that have a particular value in `subjects` (eg. subject = 'English')?

Data:

```
[
  {
    "node": {
      "name": "Miss Jones",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "John",
          "subjects": ["English", "Maths"]
        },
        {
          "name": "Sarah",
          "subjects": ["Geography"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "node": {
      "name": "Mr Hudson",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "Joe",
          "subjects": ["Maths", "French"]
        },
        {
          "name": "Samantha",
          "subjects": ["English"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "node": {
      "name": "Miss Jones",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "John",
          "subjects": ["English", "Maths"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "node": {
      "name": "Mr Hudson",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "Samantha",
          "subjects": ["English"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the function `map` like other answers are suggesting, even when the handler is mutating the original array.

Just use the function `forEach` for looping and the function `filter` along with the function `includes` for checking the array `subjects`.

```js
const arr = [  {    "node": {      "name": "Miss Jones",      "students": [        {          "name": "John",          "subjects": ["English", "Maths"]        },        {          "name": "Sarah",          "subjects": ["Geography"]        }      ]    }  },  {    "node": {      "name": "Mr Hudson",      "students": [        {          "name": "Joe",          "subjects": ["Maths", "French"]        },        {          "name": "Samantha",          "subjects": ["English"]        }      ]    }  }],
      subject = 'English';
  
arr.forEach(o => o.node.students = o.node.students.filter(s => s.subjects.includes(subject)));

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with `map` and `filter`.

```js
let nodes = [
  {
    "node": {
      "name": "Miss Jones",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "John",
          "subjects": ["English", "Maths"]
        },
        {
          "name": "Sarah",
          "subjects": ["Geography"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "node": {
      "name": "Mr Hudson",
      "students": [
        {
          "name": "Joe",
          "subjects": ["Maths", "French"]
        },
        {
          "name": "Samantha",
          "subjects": ["English"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const englishNodes = nodes.map(n => {
  n.node.students = n.node.students.filter(s => s.subjects.includes('English'));
  return n;
});

console.log(englishNodes);
```

Comment: This would not correct for case students don't have English subject. It will return a node with empty students. Please see my answer

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming every node has at least one student with English as a subject. If not you can always run filter on the top level array again to select only those nodes with a non empty students array.

Comment: Function map is definitely useless!

Comment: @Ele not if you want to filter `nodes` further to include only those that have non empty students :D

Comment: @slider function `map` is for conversion rather than filtering objects.

Comment: @Ele I was suggesting `nodes.map(... ...).filter(n => n.node.students.length > 0)`. How would you do this without `map`? But I agree, if we're mutating the original array, `map` isn't ideal. We should return a new node object with the new filtered `students` array or go with just `forEach` if we're mutating the original.

Answer (score 1):

I would filter the data using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const data = [{ "node": { "name": "Miss Jones", "students": [{ "name": "John", "subjects": ["English", "Maths"] }, { "name": "Sarah", "subjects": ["Geography"] }] } }, { "node": { "name": "Mr Hudson", "students": [{ "name": "Joe", "subjects": ["Maths", "French"] }, { "name": "Samantha", "subjects": ["English"] }] } }];

const results = data.map(({ node }) => {
    const students = node.students.filter(student =>
        student.subjects.includes('English'));
    return {
        node: {
            ...node,
            students
        }
    };
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: This would not correct for case students don't have English. It will return a node with empty students. Please see my answer

Comment: Yes it will return an empty student array and that is the required, he only want the students with English subject.

Comment: Function map is definitely useless!

Comment: Now i am not mutating the original array. Is this better

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do is transforming data, not only filter. Please try the following:

```
data.map((o) => {
  o.students = o.node.students.filter((s) => s.subjects.indexOf("English") >= 0);
  if (o.students.length >= 0) return o;
  return null;
}).filter((o) => o);
```

You have to return null for students that does not have `English` subject, then filter null to ignore them

Comment: Function map is definitely useless!

Comment: @Ele Why it is useless?